# How to install foobnix on debian 8?

Tags: debian

Recently, I am working with `Debial`. I familiarized with `foobnix` and want to use it but it is impossible to install it.
Writing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player
```

I get:

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Comment: Referring to this article, http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/ you need to install this package: 'sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties'

Comment: @Mikkel `# sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties`
`E: Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
E: Не удалось выполнить блокировку управляющего каталога (/var/lib/dpkg/); он уже используется другим процессом?`

Answer (score 0):

By default `add-apt-repository` isn't installed on debian , you should install the `python-software-properties` package to get the command working:

To install `foobnix` run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install foobnix
```

**Edit**

Download the `.deb` package and install it as follows:

```
wget https://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/f/foobnix/foobnix_2.6.10-dmo1_all.deb
dpkg -i foobnix_2.6.10-dmo1_all.deb
apt-get -f install
foobnix
```

Comment: # `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player` 
`sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common && sudo apt-get update` then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player`

Comment: #`sudo apt-get install foobnix` 
`Чтение списков пакетов… Готово` 
`Построение дерева зависимостей`        
`Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово` 
`E: Не удалось найти пакет foobnix`

Comment: $ `foobnix` 
`bash: foobnix: команда не найдена`